PCA mapping points with the same feature vector in the original space
I am applying PCA using scikit learn on the following toy dataset:
$$[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]\\
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]\\
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]$$
I want to reduce the dimension to 2 components. This is what I get:
$$ [[ 0.92372131  1.31638362]\\
 [ 0.99857109 , 0.1731043 ]\\
 [ 0.36124164 ,-1.2391385 ]\\
 [ 0.85429835 ,-0.71911047]\\
 [ 0.36124164 ,-1.2391385 ]\\
 [ 0.99857109 , 0.1731043 ]\\
 [ 0.92372131 , 1.31638362]\\
 [ 0.85429835 ,-0.71911047]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]\\
 [-0.69729608 , 0.10416912]]$$
Now let us consider row 1 and row 7 in the original space. They are identical and the PCA map them in the same points (row 1 and 7 of the reduced space).
The question is why PCA map in the same points all the last rows? They are different. Some of them are identical like row 12 and 14, but this do not justify the result.

Since you're projecting to the top two principal components, if some datapoints are identical along these components (while being different along other ones), then their projections will be the same.
It's like how [1,0,1] and [1,0,0] are different, but when you project to the first two components (which might be the first two principal components) they are the same.
